# Mixing C++ and C/C++ static library with CMake

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, g++, c99

I have searched various forums and cannot find a solution to my problem. 
I'm trying to write unit tests of a function in a C file. I'm using google test library.
Although I follow the guides, the project doesn't compile properly. 
Tests written in C ++ do not see functions in C file. (undefined reference)
Below I am attaching my files, maybe someone will notice where I made a mistake. I'm out of ideas.

[image: Project tree]

pir_driver.h

```
#ifndef PIR_DRIVER_H_
#define PIR_DRIVER_H_

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t xTaskGetTickCount();


#ifdef __cplusplus
} /* extern "C" */
#endif
```

pir_driver.c

```
#include "pir_driver.h"

uint32_t xTaskGetTickCount()
{
    return 1000;
}
```

pir_test.cpp

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include "../pir_driver.h"

TEST(PIR_Timer_Test, Start)
{
    uint32_t test =  xTaskGetTickCount() * 2;
    EXPECT_EQ(test, test);

}
```

Project root CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
set(This pir_driver)
project(${This} C CXX)
include(Dart)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
enable_testing()
add_subdirectory(googletest)
set(Headers
    pir_driver.h
)
set(Source
    pir_driver.c
)
add_library(${This} STATIC ${Sources} ${Headers})
set_target_properties(${This} PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE C)
add_subdirectory(test)
```

test CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
set(This pir_test)
set(Sources pir_test.cpp )

add_executable(${This} ${Sources})
set_target_properties(${This} PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
target_link_libraries(${This} PUBLIC pir_driver gtest_main )

add_test( NAME ${This} COMMAND ${This})
```

Compile log:

```
[proc] Wykonywanie polecenia: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build c:/Users/xxx/ansi_c_projects/pir_test/build --config Debug --target all -- -j 10
[build] [ 14%] Linking C static library libpir_driver.a
[build] [ 28%] Building CXX object googletest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/src/gtest-all.cc.obj
[build] [ 28%] Built target pir_driver
[build] [ 42%] Linking CXX static library ..\lib\libgtestd.a
[build] [ 42%] Built target gtest
[build] [ 57%] Building CXX object googletest/CMakeFiles/gtest_main.dir/src/gtest_main.cc.obj
[build] [ 71%] Linking CXX static library ..\lib\libgtest_maind.a
[build] [ 71%] Built target gtest_main
[build] [ 85%] Building CXX object test/CMakeFiles/pir_test.dir/pir_test.cpp.obj
[build] [100%] Linking CXX executable pir_test.exe
[build] CMakeFiles\pir_test.dir/objects.a(pir_test.cpp.obj): In function `PIR_Timer_Test_Start_Test::TestBody()':
[build] C:/Users/xxx/ansi_c_projects/pir_test/test/pir_test.cpp:13: undefined reference to `xTaskGetTickCount'
[build] collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[build] mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [test\CMakeFiles\pir_test.dir\build.make:108: test/pir_test.exe] Error 1
[build] mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:1004: test/CMakeFiles/pir_test.dir/all] Error 2
[build] mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:113: all] Error 2
```

Comment: Placing an `#include` directive for a system header inside of an `extern "C"` block is probably not a good idea. Just sayin'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is that you have a typo in the main `CMakeLists.txt`: You define the variable `Source`, but use the variable `Sources` when populating the sources of the `pir_driver` target. Consequently the .c file isn't compiled and the linker can't find the symbol defined within.

The missing .c file is also the reason why you needed to manually set the linker language in the first place. Once you add the source file you can remove the `set_target_properties(${This} PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE C)` line as CMake will figure it out itself based on the extensions of the source files.

To avoid such problems in the future you can use

```
add_library(pir_driver STATIC)
target_sources(pir_driver
  PRIVATE
    pir_driver.h
    pir_driver.c
)
```

instead of CMake variables to collect sources and headers in CMake 3.11 and later.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I see the risk of using variables. I'm just getting to know CMAKE. Target_include_directories was still missing, but the error was unequivocal.